# Laravel relation on 2 fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a football **Game** which has a **home_team** and an **away_team**

My relations for Game.php are as follows:

```
public function hometeam()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Team::class, 'id', 'home_team_id');
}

public function awayteam()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Team::class, 'id', 'away_team_id');
}
```

> Now I want to see for each **Team** on which games it belongs.

I've tried the following in Team.php but it's returning *null*

```
public function homeGames()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Game', 'home_team_id', 'id');
}

public function awayGames()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Game', 'away_team_id', 'id');
}
```

And the same for away_team_id offcourse.

Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your games table have 2 foreign keys of teams table, one for the home team and one for the away team? (one to many relationship).

That way, you could do something like `$team->homeGames` and `$team->awayGames` and you will get all home games and away games for a specific team.

Also, the Team model should have 2 x `return $this->hasMany(Game::class);` methods while the Game model should have 2 x `return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);`

Update:

Team.php model

```
class Team extends Model 
{
     public function homeGames() 
     {
         return $this->hasMany(Game::class, 'id', 'home_team_id');
     }

     public function awayGames() 
     {
        return $this->hasMany(Game::class, 'id', 'away_team_id');
     }
}
```

Game.php model

```
class Game extends Model 
{
     public function homeTeam() 
     {
         return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'home_team_id', 'id');
     }

     public function awayTeam() 
     {
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'away_team_id', 'id');
     }
}
```

Comment: did you add any dummy data? Also, the Team model should have 2 x `return $this->hasMany(Game::class);` methods while the Game model should have 2 x `return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);`

Comment: Aha That's the solution! :) Thank you, if you edit your answer I'll accept it

Comment: Hmh I'm a bit confused by the order of the keys then. In Team.php with the hasMany, should it be ->hasMany(Team::class, 'home_team_id', 'id') or first the 'id' and then the 'home_team_id', thanks!

Comment: yeah, it should be like that. I forgot to mention the foreign keys

Comment: Could you post the full code? so I can accept this answer :) Thank you!

Comment: OK I added the 2 classes, anything else missing?